# How did Starbucks send bold text in an MMS to Messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, sms, formatting

I received the discount message shown below from Starbucks on iOS 7.0.3.  Somehow they managed to make part of the message text bold.  How did they do this, or better, how can I recreate it?

[image: MMS from Starbucks with formatted text]

I tried sending a formatted email to my phone number, but it was converted to plain text, as I've thought all SMS/MMS messages are.

*Note: The **bold text** accessibility setting in Settings is set to off.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **Settings > Messages**, turn on **Show Subject Field**. The subject will display in bold when an MMS is sent.

Comment: You're right.  It looks like I've just never seen the SMS / MMS subject field actually used.